# how to refresh access token when it expires without using redux

Tags: reactjs, jwt, refresh-token

i so far handled logging in and access to the routes using a privateRoute component but if the token expires the user will be kicked out and should login again

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...res}) => (
<Route
{...res}
render={props =>
  (localStorage.getItem('access-token') && (new Date().getTime() / 1000) <= parseInt(localStorage.getItem('expires-at')) ) ?
    (<Component
      {...props} />) :
    (<Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: {from:props.location}
}}/>)
}
/>
)
```

i want to set the refreshToken request without kicking the user out and i dont want to use redux